# Error while looping on polygon geopandas column, within() function not working

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have a dataframe with Polygons and would like to loop in order to create a new column checking if a specific point is within one or more polygons (as they are not exclusive). I tried to follow a tutorial of geopandas but this doesn't seem to be working as all the columns return a "False". Can one please indicate what I am doing wrong?
Many thanks.
Just in case, the file "quartier_paris.geojson" is a classic geojson file, it is read without problem (shapes appear and I can go all quartiers.explore() for example and see all the polygons on the map and I am 100% positive that the point is within those polygons. The size of the file is too big to be uloaded though, this is the link for it just in case https://parisdata.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/quartier_paris/download/?format=geojson&timezone=Europe/Berlin&lang=fr)

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import os
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, Point

quartiers = geopandas.read_file("quartier_paris.geojson")
p1 = Point(48.823, 2.30)  
quartiers["Match"] =quartiers["geometry"].apply(lambda x: p1.within(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your point is not in any of the geometries.  Additionally you have transposed longitude and latitude
- when transposed it is within rectangular boundary of geometry
- below code shows tests and a **plotly** mapbox to demonstrate

```
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, Point, box
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

res = requests.get(
    "https://parisdata.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/quartier_paris/download/?format=geojson&timezone=Europe/Berlin&lang=fr"
)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(res.json())
p1 = Point(48.823, 2.30)
p2 = Point(2.30, 48.823)

print(
    f"""
p1 in total bounds: {p1.within(box(*gdf.total_bounds))}
p2 in total bounds: {p2.within(box(*gdf.total_bounds))}
p2 in any geometry: gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda g: p2.within(g)).any()
"""
)

px.scatter_mapbox(lon=[p2.x], lat=[p2.y]).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom": 10,
        "layers": [
            {"source": gdf["geometry"].__geo_interface__, "type": "line"},
            {
                "source": gdf["geometry"]
                .apply(lambda g: box(*g.bounds))
                .__geo_interface__,
                "type": "line",
                "color": "skyblue",
            },
            {
                "source": box(*gdf.total_bounds).__geo_interface__,
                "type": "line",
                "color": "blue",
            },
        ],
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
).update_traces(marker_size=20)
```

[image]